# make php loop echo content once

Tags: php, html, linux

i have a php page that checks if a file is on the server and makes it echo Online if the file is found but it does this forever and i only want it to do it once.

```
<h3 class="monospace sec2">Server status: </h3>
  <?php
  ob_start();
  while(true){
    $filename = '/var/www/html/.online';

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo '<span style="color:#00FF00;text-align:center;">Online</span>';
        ob_end_clean();
    } else {
        echo '<span style="color:#ff0000;text-align:center;">Offline</span>';
        ob_end_clean();
    }
  }
  ?>
</div>
```

it keeps echoing online and continues to make the page longer i just want it to print once. can you please help me.

Comment: Just remove the while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you just want to print something when the status of the file changes, so this is the code you are looking for:

```php
<h3 class="monospace sec2">Server status: </h3>
<?php

$online = null;
ob_start();

while (true) {
    $filename = '/var/www/html/.online';

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        if ($online !== true) {
            echo '<span style="color:#00FF00;text-align:center;">Online</span>';
            ob_end_clean();

            $online = true;
        }
    } else {
        if ($online !== false) {
            echo '<span style="color:#ff0000;text-align:center;">Offline</span>';
            ob_end_clean();

            $online = false;
        }

    }
    
    // Please consider introducing a sleep here. No need to check if the file exist every millisecond.
    // sleep(1);
}

?>
</div>
```